# How to override this block and template in my module?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, overrides

I want to override these two files in a module:

Block:

> /magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/Form.php

Template:

> /magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to override file in your custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Block use the below code in your module's di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method\Form" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method\Form"/>
</config>
```

For phtml override create a xml file with name sales_order_create_load_block_shipping_method.xml on your module's layout folder and set template for this "order.create.shipping.method.form" and use your template file location as per the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For **block** file.

> app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/Form.php

And for **html** file.

> app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml

This will work.